# Need guidance for complicated query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So here's a little background on the system. User's battle and the winner is the one who wins the most rounds. I need help with possibly joining three tables. I have table `user` one, which stores the user info. Table `match` which stores match information. Table `rounds` which stores the winner of every rounds per match, so if a match has 5 rounds, then table `rounds` will have five rows for that match and will record the winner of each round.

Here's some sample data:
Table `user`:
(`userid` is the primary key)

```
userid   username
-----------------
  1       Kevin
  2       Sam
  3       Steve
  4       Matt
```

Table `match`:
(`id` is the primary key. `challenger` and `challenged` are both foreign keys to `user.userid`)

```
 id  challenger  challenged  rounds
-----------------------------------
 1      2           3          3
 2      1           2          1
 3      2           3          3
 4      2           4          1
```

Table `rounds`:
(all fields are the primary key. `id` is foreign key to `match.id` and `winner` is foreign key to `user.userid`)

```
 id  round  winner
------------------
 1    1       2
 1    2       2
 1    3       3
 2    1       1
 3    1       2
 3    2       3
 3    3       2
 4    1       4
```

I'm trying to build a query that will output the following results:

```
winner  won   loser  won  
------------------------
 Sam     2    Steve   1
 Kevin   1    Sam     0
 Sam     2    Steve   1
 Matt    1    Sam     0
```

The above results shows the winner and loser of each of match. The `won` field shows the number of rounds won for that match for the winner and loser respectively.

Does anyone know how I can build the above query?

Comment: Also important here, I think, is what happens if they tie? Or can we assume there will always be an odd number of rounds?

Comment: yes, there's always an odd number

Comment: I think you should consider determining wins as they happen and storing the result in the row for each match. So, add another field to match called winner, and fill it with the user's id as soon as the match is over. You'll save yourself a whole lot of overhead compared to calculating the wins with a gigantic query like in some of the answers I'm seeing every single time you need the results. Plus, it's much simpler that way. If that's feasible for your project, I feel like that's a much better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    case when w1 > w2 then u1 else u2 end as winner,
    case when w1 > w2 then w1 else w2 end as won,
    case when w1 > w2 then u2 else u1 end as loser,
    case when w1 > w2 then w2 else w1 end as won
from (
    select m.id, u1.username as u1, u2.username as u2, 
        count(r1.winner) as w1,
        count(r2.winner) as w2
    from match m
    join user u1 on m.challenger = u1.userid
    join user u2 on m.challenged = u2.userid
    join rounds r on r.id = m.id
    left join rounds r1 on r.id = r1.id and r.round = r1.round and r1.winner = u1.userid
    left join rounds r2 on r.id = r2.id and r.round = r2.round and r2.winner = u2.userid
    group by m.id, u1.username, u2.username
) t
```

It relies on ([Problems with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-null.html)):

> Aggregate (summary) functions such as COUNT(), MIN(), and SUM() **ignore NULL values**.

and here it is an advantage.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select match_id,
       case when challenger_wins > challenged_wins 
            then challenger_name else challenged_name end) winner,
       case when challenger_wins > challenged_wins 
            then challenger_wins else challenged_wins end) winner_won,
       case when challenger_wins < challenged_wins 
            then challenger_name else challenged_name end) loser,
       case when challenger_wins < challenged_wins 
            then challenger_wins else challenged_wins end) loser_won
from
(select m.id match_id,
        max(case when u.userid = m.challenger 
                 then u.username end) challenger_name,
        sum(case when u.userid = m.challenger 
                 then r.wins else 0 end) challenger_wins,
        max(case when u.userid = m.challenged 
                 then u.username end) challenged_name,
        sum(case when u.userid = m.challenged 
                 then r.wins else 0 end) challenged_wins
 from match m
 join user u on u.userid in (m.challenger, m.challenged)
 left join 
 (select id, winner, count(*) wins
  from round
  group by id, winner) r
 on m.id = r.id and u.userid = r.winner
 group by m.id) v
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
SELECT
  IF(won1 >= won2, username1, username2) winner,
  IF(won1 >= won2, won1, won2) won,
  IF(won1 < won2, username1, username2) loser,
  IF(won1 < won2, won1, won2) won
FROM (
  SELECT u1.username username1, u2.username username2, COALESCE(r1.rounds, 0) won1, COALESCE(r2.rounds, 0) won2 FROM `match` m
    JOIN user u1
      ON u1.userid = m.challenger
    JOIN user u2
      ON u2.userid = m.challenged
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, COUNT(round) rounds, winner FROM rounds GROUP BY id, winner) r1
      ON r1.id = m.id AND r1.winner = u1.userid
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, COUNT(round) rounds, winner FROM rounds GROUP BY id, winner) r2
      ON r2.id = m.id AND r2.winner = u2.userid
  ) t
```